# React-Router: How to avoid wrapping <Route /> elements in div

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

How do I avoid using a wrapping  for all my routes in App.js?
(using react-route v4)

App.js

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div> // <-- I want to avoid this div to have cleaner css
        <Route path="/" component={Analytics} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page_1} />
        <Route exact path="/page-2" component={Page_2} />
        <Route exact path="/page-3" component={Page_3} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
      </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: How has this not got more answers... What about if Router has links too.. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before react 16 you had to do this, as of react 16.2 you can use `Fragments`: see https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

e.g.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment> //could also be just <>
        <Route path="/" component={Analytics} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page_1} />
        <Route exact path="/page-2" component={Page_2} />
        <Route exact path="/page-3" component={Page_3} />
      <React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

or if you would prefer you could return an array of elements:

```
      render() {
        return [
            <Route key="1" path="/" component={Analytics} />,
            <Route key="2" exact path="/" component={Page_1} />,
            <Route key="3" exact path="/page-2" component={Page_2} />,
            <Route key="4" exact path="/page-3" component={Page_3} />
        ]
      }
```

(remember to put keys in)